# The arguments of the array in the COUNTIFS have different sizes

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, countif

```
=SUMPRODUCT(arrayformula(COUNTIFS(
'All'!$B$2:$B, SPLIT(HLOOKUP(A18,'Funnel'!$A$1:$D$4,4,FALSE),"|"),
DAY('All'!$C$12:$C), DAY(C13),
MONTH('All'!$C$12:$C), MONTH(C13),
YEAR('All'!$C$12:$C), YEAR(C13),
'All'!H:H, A12)))
```

This formula returns an "array arguments to countif are of different size" error how do I fix it
I have already added arrayformula but still it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*the error-code `of different size` itself is self-explanatory. your `criteria_range` **Column_B** starts at **row_2**; date **Column_C** starts at **row_12**; **Column_H** starts at **row_1***